# gmail sign in not working what should i do?

Tags: kotlin, firebase-authentication

`getString(R.string.default_web_client_id)` 
not resolved string thats why gmail dialog closes on gmail account selection

```
val gso = GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
            .requestEmail()
            .build()
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you follow all the steps specified in the [Guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/google-signin)

Make sure also your  SHA-1 fingerprint is correct in Firebase.

If you haven't yet specified your app's SHA-1 fingerprint, do so from the [Settings page](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/settings/general/) of the Firebase console. See [Authenticating Your Client](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/client-auth) for details on how to get your app's SHA-1 fingerprint